# Choosing between voltage and current

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-design

I am always confused between varying voltage versus current in a circuit. Why cannot we keep a standard voltage source (say 12V) and simply change the resistance to vary the current accordingly.

What are the advantages of varying voltage? And what are the advantages of varying the current?

Comment: Generally for big-picture questions like this, the answer is cost. Out of all the ways we know how to do it (light a room, play video games, talk to someone across town), the way you see people doing it is probably about the lowest-cost way we've found to do it (subject to some limits like not electrocuting the user, and accidents of history like some countries having 50 Hz and others having 60 Hz mains).

Comment: Closed as too broad because .. it depends. Most circuits *are* at a standard voltage source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a circuit?  Or in a product?

In products that's exactly what we do: provide a standard voltage-source called a "power supply," then let various sections of circuitry each draw whatever current they need at the moment.   Or, we provide voltage-signals on the inputs, and the outputs provide different voltage-signals.

In general we don't vary the current: don't provide constant-current power supplies.   In choosing between voltage and current, we chose voltage.

Look at any product schematic and you'll find the voltage for the power supply (sometimes several, sometimes just one.)   But usually the current won't be given.  It's unknown.  You might see a max current rating, but the actual value of amperes is somewhere below that value.  Each schematic section is drawing a range of different currents depending on the tasks it's performing at the moment.  In other words, the resistances are varying, and the amperes change in proportion, but the power supply voltage remains fixed.

To find the power supply voltages, look at the circuit schematic.  But to find the values for current, you'll have to measure them.

Answer (score 0):

We can't keep a standard voltage, because that voltage will not work for all applications. It will either be so low that we get absolutely enormous losses for power transmission, or it would be too high for the insulation in small electronic components. Or it is too high to be safe to touch, etc.

We can't always just adjust the resistance to adjust the current consumption, like you suggested. circuits/components will inherently have a specific impedance, and all circuits and/or components have a maximum power dissipation. Some loads may even have varying impedance, then how should you handle that if you already limited the current to it, using a resistor?

It's not explicitly impossible to choose a strategy that you ask for, but it does not make any sense, neither cost wise or technically or practically.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in DC domain only. But what about AC? Did you consider that? There are parasitic inductances and capacitances everywhere. That means that circuit will have higher power consumption with higher voltages and higher frequencies.

Another reason is that transistors inside IC's are getting smaller and smaller, and the breakdown voltage is getting smaller and smaller accordingly to that.

That's why many IC's went from 12V to 5V, then to 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.8V, etc. now some IC's operating at 0.8V.

Answer (score 0):

The question clearly applies to heaters (because otherwise it makes not much of sense), so there are all kinds of heaters, Including 12v heaters with different resistance.

There are also different available voltage sources in different applications, so it is reasonable to have heaters for other voltages too, so you could avoid converters for cost, space and general simplicity.

By the way, current sources are significantly less available.